# How to install pip as Python module (.py) and not as executable (.exe)?

Tags: python, pip

I've been trying to use 'pip' in the Python shell - something that should be very simple. I am told by everyone that all I need to do is to open the shell and call:

```
pip install <name-of-some-package>
```

Output:

```
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined
```

After peeking into the Scripts folder where 'pip' is supposed to live, I notice that it is not really a .py but a .exe. 'easy_install' also suffered the same fate. They were installed together with the Python standard distribution from python.org.

Why is pip installed as a binary file? Can I get it as a module so I can run it from the Python shell?

Comment: You can run compiled executables (.exe) from python with the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Pip is installed as a .py module when you install it properly. The .exe is just a convenience thing for you to call it on windows. The .exe doesn't work if pip is not correctly installed in first place

Comment: @nosklo This is the second time I install the Python distribution and, the first time, pip was a module. I followed the exact same procedure.
The executable works fine from command prompt. It is just annoying not to be able to run from Python shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip.exe` is just a thin binary wrapper (a Setuptools wrapper to be exact) that ends up doing loading the `pip` package's entry point. It's installed when you install `pip`.  On Unixes, like Linux or macOS, the "executable" is actually just an executable Python script, but does the same thing.

You can do `python -m pip` too, which is (practically) equivalent to running the `pip` (or `pip.exe`) wrapper. (Note this may not hold for other packages, but it does for Pip.)

`import pip` will also work; the actual guts of Pip exist in your Python's `lib/site-packages` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run pip from **python shell** you have to use python commands, not shell commands.

Try this:

```
from pip._internal import main
main(['install', 'requests'])
```